# How to convert Embedded image to Base64 string in xamarin forms..?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to convert an Embedded image to base 64 string. The image is in PCL solution so let me know how to convert an image into base64. As I tried lots of ways but I am not getting the file path properly. So please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly take a look around and see how to ask a proper question in this community.

Comment: Well, I have a question Mosin, This image in your PCL solution that you want to convert to Base64 is it An [Embedded image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images)?

Comment: @G.hakim yes it is Embedded Image..

Comment: Okay posting an answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

```
//file to base64 string
byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
String s = Convert.ToBase64String(b);

//base64 string to file
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(FileName2, data);
```

Comment: I have tried another solution and modified my answer can you check this?

Comment: i tries another solution..its gives error like cannot Xamarin.Forms.Image  to byte[]

Comment: I have modified my answer can you check this?

Comment: My image is Embedded image or resource image...they are already in solution...so i am getting proper path of image...so this answer is also not worked

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an embedded resource getting the path for the image is a problem to convert it into a stream, you can take the following steps to get the path of your embedded image:

```
string imagePath = "NameOfProject.Assets.applicationIcon.png";
```

**Note:** This is the sample path in your case you will give your path, Where the name of the project is the name of the project, Assets is the folder in which I have the image and application icon is the image. (I hope you understood what I am doing here)

After that get the Assembly details something like this:

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(NameOfClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
```

Then inside a using statement convert your image into a stream, Something like this

```
string result;
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(imagePath))
{
  long length = stream.Length;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
  stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)length);
  result = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
}
```

Revert in case of queries.